Spring Strict HttpFirewall and query parameters with malicious pattersn like ../../
I have jwt secured spring boot api 3.2.7
I am trying to add strict Http Firewall like below.
@Bean
@Primary
public HttpFirewall configureFirewall() {
  StrictHttpFirewall strictHttpFirewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
  return strictHttpFirewall;
}

When I am trying to send request with query parametes like ../../.
The request is not rejected but it is making through
will StrictHttpFirewall block request like this?
